# IntelliJ IDEA - compare ignore comments

Tags: git, intellij-idea, diff

Hi I would like to ask if there is some easy way to compare ignoring comments. When I generate java classes from xsd I am totally overwhelmed with the changes including when the file was generated that it is easy to lose the changes in code.

[image: emphasized text]

Answer (score 3):

There is no such option that would help ignore comments during a diff.

There is a feature request for that, please vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113681